# Generic solution for disabling fields for non-authorized users

Tags: angular, authorization

I have a project whose client side language is Angular 2. My application has a few pages and all of them have different permissions. For example, I have an employees page, a books page, a locations page, a clocking page, etc.

Each of this pages has CanEdit and CanView permissions. A logged in user may have CanEdit permission for locations, but he may not have CanEdit permissions for the books page.

I want to make a generic solution that I will write on one place and will work for all the pages, I don't want repeating code in all the pages. Something like: if the user has CanEdit permissions for the current page, remove the read-only attribute for all the inputs, and if he doesn't have the CanEdit permissions, add the read-only attribute.

At the moment there are no roles in the project but I'm open to suggestions.

Is this possible to be done?

Answer (score 2):

The best solumtion I can imagine is to create a service with the status of CanEdit and CanView of the user. Then, on your html page, use :

```
<button *ngIf="userService.CanView">a button</button>
```

to show/hide (in fact, to make it exist or not) the elements you want to be displayed

Comment: You mean in the service the user will have statuses like: CanViewLocations, CanEditLocations, CanViewBooks, CanEditBooks for every page of the application?

Comment: Depend on the level of precision you want on the rights. The most basic way is to have only two statuses : CanView and CanEdit, end use them on any page. You just have to put a *ngIf condition on buttons/fields/divs you want to protect

Comment: why `CanView` and not `canView`?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using directives like CanView, CanRead and a shared service that will check if the user can read or edit the page. In the directive, you will be able to redirect the user if he don't have the CanView right, or disable all inputs if he don't have the CanEdit permission